# Map jdbi query result to a map keyed on a column with a list of values

Tags: java, sql, jdbi, jdbi3, jdbi3-core

Imagine a scenario where I am querying the orders table for a list of users and trying to find their orders. I am trying to get a map, with a keyset of user ids, and a list of order objects.
return type is similar to this - Map<Integer, List>

```
 JdbiHelper.jdbi(readOnly).withHandle(
                handle -> handle.createQuery(query)
                        .bindList("user_id", userIds).?
```

The query itself is like :-

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE user_id in (<userIds>)
```

How do I get a map, with key as user ids and list of order objects as values?

I was trying something along these lines

```
    JdbiHelper.jdbi(readOnly).withHandle(
                handle -> handle.createQuery(query)
                        .bindList("user_id", userIds)
                        .map((rs, ctx) -> Pair.of(rs.getInt("user_id"), rs))
                        .collect(toMap(Pair::getLeft, Pair::getRight))
```

but, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need a result mapper, e.g. an OrderMapper which turns a result set into an Order object.

Here is a solution using the Guava ImmutableListMultimap (which maps onto a list or results). Otherwise, you have to write your own Collector that collects the resulting Order objects into a `Map<Integer, List<Order>>`.

```
OrderMapper mapper = new OrderMapper();

Multimap<Integer, Order> results = JdbiHelper.jdbi(readOnly).withHandle(
                handle -> handle.createQuery("SELECT * from orders WHERE user_id IN (<user_id>)")
                        .bindList("user_id", userIds)
                        .mapTo(Order.class)
                        .collect(toImmutableListMultimap(Order::getUserId, Functions.identity())));
```

Or you can register the OrderMapper with Jdbi using `Jdbi.registerColumnMapper(new OrderMapper())` and use `.mapTo(Order.class)` instead of the `.map(mapper)`.

In any case you need a mapper to turn the result set into an Order object.

```
public class OrderMapper implements ColumnMapper<Order> {

    public Order map(ResultSet r, int columnNumber, StatementContext ctx) throws SQLException {
        return new Order().setUserId(rs.getInt("user_id"),
                ... additional columns ...
        }
    }
```